# Not getting unmasked creditcard details for GetElectronicDocumentRQ service

Tags: sabre

I got a response, but the problem is the credit card details I am getting are masked, and I want a ccexpiry field for this. I have also added searchParameters.CCView = true. Any help would be appreciated

I have also added searchParameters.CCView = true.